# Does steady flow imply laminar?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, turbulence

Most secondary school textbooks, in their chapter about fluid dynamics, seem to suggest that "steady flow" and "laminar flow" are synonyms.

Though I never received any fluid mechanics course when I was at the university, it's pretty obvious to me that flows can be laminar but non-steady.
But what about the converse? Can a steady flow be non-laminar?

If I skim through more advanced textbooks and lecture notes, I can't find any direct reference of a strict relation between the two concepts, neither positive nor negative. Yet "between the lines" most of the texts seem to take as a fact that steady implies laminar.

Is that true? Is a steady non-laminar flow something theoretically possible in some context (eg. inviscid flow in a purely continuum-mechanical model of a fluid) but physically unobtainable in any actual fluid? Is the implication blatantly false?

My imagination has apparently no problem at visualizing some sort of weird self-intersecting (and consequently non-laminar?) flow which doesn't vary over time. 
Am I missing something? I definitely guess that I am.

Comment: Since the discussion isn't directly addressing the point I'm more concerned about, I'll try to make my request more concrete (by expliciting some - I understand, questionable - definitions):

Let's assume that "steady" means that for any point the (partial) time derivative of the velocity field is zero. 
And let's say that "laminar" reduces to asking that streamlines be well-defined and not self-intersecting.

If my definition of fluid permits situations where two or more currents pass through each other, can I have a steady, non-laminar flow? If need be setting viscosity to 0?

Comment: Keep in mind that real turbulent flows are inherently unsteady flows, i.e. their flow patterns are constantly changing. It is however possible to define a statistically steady state where the averaged flow field doesn't change in time

Comment: 'Steady' by your definition (which I think is standard) seems to me to directly imply there is no turbulence. Turbulent flows necessarily involve changes in the velocity field over time. I think a lot of people are taking 'steady' to mean 'statistically stable', which turbulent flows can be. (you could, however, have laminar flows that are not steady, I think).

Comment: Yes, you could have laminar flows that aren't steady-state. If a slow laminar flow is accelerated slowly, without increasing the $Re$ number too much, it will remain laminar during that transience. No problemo.

Answer (score 5):

The answer depends on your definition of "steady". A flow is called turbulent when small oscillations are no longer damped, but instead excited. Therefore when looking at the fluid on a microscopic scale, a turbulent flow is not steady.

However, turbulence can be modeled on a macroscopic scale (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence_modeling), effectively encapsulating the local non-steadiness. Thus on a macroscopic scale, turbulent flow can be steady.

An example for a (macroscopic) partially turbulent steady flow is the flow around an airfoil. At the nose, the flow is laminar. At some point (the transition point) at both upper and lower surface, the flow becomes turbulent. (The location of the transition point for a dedicated airfoils is depending on flow velocity and the angle of attack.)

Answer (score 3):

> Most secondary school textbooks, in their chapter about fluid dynamics, seem to suggest that "steady flow" and "laminar flow" are synonyms.

You'll have to point to specific textbooks because mine don't say that, primarily because it is incorrect.

By steady flow simply understand *constant flow rate*. Understood that way, steady flow can be laminar, turbulent (or in that grey area between the two). Constant (volumetric) flow rate says nothing about the [Reynolds Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) at all.

---

**Edit:**

Illustrating laminar (top) and turbulent (bottom) flow, with associated radial flow speed gradients:

[image: Laminar and turbulent flow/]

For laminar flow the radial speed distribution is given by:

$$v(r)=v_m\bigg(1-\frac{r^2}{R^2}\bigg)$$

Suitable integration between $0$ and $R$ gives the volumetric flow rate $F$:

$$F=A\frac{v_m}{2}$$

With $A$ the cross-section.

For turbulent flow (velocity profile not very well drawn), the exponent $2$ becomes much higher and the velocity gradient $v(r)$ much flatter near the centre. Here too, volumetric flow rate can be obtained by integration over $0$ to $R$. At very high Reynolds Numbers, then $\frac{dv(r)}{dt} \approx 0$.

Comment: Eh? Steady flow should mean that the fluid variables (in particular, the speed distribution) are time-independent. This seems obviously incompatible with turbulence.

Comment: No, it's not, A well established turbulent flow would have a velocity *macro-distribution* that's time invariant. Not so at the micro-level, obviously.

Comment: Well, ok, upvoting then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a steady flow is always laminar (but not conversely as you already understood). Turbulent flows are by definition time-dependent (and thus unsteady) flows and therefore not laminar.

Turbulent flows can however be [statistically stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_dynamics#Steady_vs_unsteady_flow). This means that average quantities (such as mean velocity, turbulent kinetic energy and even higher moments), do not change in time (if you take a different time range).

Comment: "Turbulent flows are by definition transient flows". Not true at all. Turbulent flows can exist forever.

Comment: @Gert Transient means time-dependent.

Comment: Yes, I speak English too. You're still wrong. That 'different time range' you talk about is the normal time range. In REAL applications.

Comment: @Gert I don't get your point. "Turbulent flows can exist forever". I agree, but where do I say something else? I thought that was your interpretation of "transient" (i.e. non-eternal). I don't get what you mean with "normal time range" in "real application"? What I mean was, that averaging over $[t_1,t_2]$ and $[t_3,t_4]$, results in the same statistics. Can you maybe expand on your comment, so that I understand my confusion? I will then improve my answer.

Comment: Firstly, read the question again: it's about *steady flow in secondary school text books*. You think they mean the RT instability? After a while flow settles to laminar, turbulent or poorly defined, forever. The initial transiency isn't highly relevant to the question, IMHO.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. In cases with a driving force (i.e. pipe flow), statistically stationary turbulent flow is real. I was not specifically referring to the initial phase, but rather trying to compare forever and "forever + 1 time unit"

Comment: I'd like to point out that my question originates from something I read on a secondary school textbook, but isn't really concerned much about secondary school physics. As a matter of fact, I'm much more interested to a continuum mechanics approach and a purely mathematical point of view on the whole issue. I feel that nobody has really answered to my initial question: from a purely logical, deductive perspective, does stationary imply laminar? Why? I think the answer requires talking about differential equations, immersion of 3D-manifolds in 3D-space... but surprisingly no one discussed that.

Comment: @Bernhard In classifying a flow *regime* the Reynolds number is a dimensionless number with no basis in the transient nature of the flow. The classification of the flow depends on velocity (over some characteristic geometry) and fluid viscosity. It does not address the transient aspects, flow development and whether flow is steady or non-steady.

Comment: @Gert please see my comment to Bernhard above

Answer (score 0):

No not necessarily. Steady flow is defined for either fully developed laminar flow, or turbulent flow. The term 'steady' applies to a non-transient nature of the flow being described within some region of space and boundaries, and statistically at a macroscopic level.

Pulsatile flows are non-steady flows and laminar flows that are not fully developed are non-steady. Although turbulent flows at a microscopic level do not have a well define velocity vector, statistical measure at a macroscopic level can, and as long as that velocity is constant, the flow can be considered steady.

Answer (score 0):

According to my concepts, Laminar flow flows in the form of sheets or lamina. So magnitude is not something that we should concern, only the direction will do the whole understanding. Steady flow is that the flow parameters are invariant of time for the fixed space. Now for the flow to be Laminar the particles in the one sheet must have the some direction (successors's direction of velocity is the same as predecessor's ) so the magnitude of the particles velocity at some fixed space( in one sheet) may or may not be same at all time i.e. the flow can be unsteady as well. For the reverse it is true as well that the steady flow can be turbulent because laminar flow is strictly direction dependent.